# How should I proceed with diagram chasing in this commutative diagram?

Tags: algebraic-topology, diagram-chasing

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology**:

> Consider a commutative diagram with exact rows:
>
> $\dots \rightarrow A_n \xrightarrow {i_n} B_n \xrightarrow {p_n} C_n \xrightarrow {d_n} A_{n-1} \rightarrow \dots$
>
> $\dots \rightarrow A_n' \xrightarrow {j_n} B_n' \xrightarrow {q_n} C_n' \xrightarrow {d_n} A_{n-1}'
>  \rightarrow \dots$
>
> with arrows $f_n,g_n$ and $h_n$ connecting $A_n \rightarrow A_n'$, $B_n \rightarrow B_n'$, and $C_n \rightarrow C_n'$.  Let $h_n$ be an isomorphism.
>
> Then there is an exact sequence $\dots \rightarrow A_n  \xrightarrow {(i_n, f_n)} B_n \oplus A'_n \xrightarrow {g_n - j_n} B_n' \xrightarrow {d_n h^{-1}_nq_n} A_{n-1} \ \rightarrow \dots$.

In particular, I'm trying to show that $\text{ker } (g_n - j_n) \subset \text{im } ((i_n, f_n))$.

I know I have to show $(b,a') \in \text{ker } (g_n - j_n) \Rightarrow \exists a \in A_n$ such that $i_n(a) = b$ and $f_n(a) = a'$.

> Since $gb = ja' \Rightarrow qgb=qja' = 0 \Rightarrow hpb = 0 \Rightarrow pb = 0 \Rightarrow b \in \text{ker $p_n$} = \text{im }i_n \Rightarrow ia=b$.

But I'm having trouble showing that $f(a) = a'$.

I figure:

> $ia=b \Rightarrow gia = gb = jfa = ja' $
>
> $\Rightarrow j(f(a) - a') = 0 \Rightarrow f(a) - a' \in \text{ker } j = \text{im } \Delta $
>
> $\Rightarrow \Delta c' = f(a) - a' \Rightarrow \Delta h c = fa - a'$

But from here I'm having trouble finding a way to show that $fa - a' = 0$.

Anyone have any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Very well-asked question!

Comment: The thing is, you found a certain $a$ such that $i_n(a)=b$, and you expect that automatically it will also satisfy $f_n(a)=a'$. But you might to choose another $a$ if you want both conditions to be satisfied simultaneously. Try to start from the fact that any $\alpha$ satisfying $i_n(\alpha)=b$ has the form $a+d_{n+1}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant $d$ when you wrote $\Delta$.

Assuming that, you have $\Delta h = f\Delta$, so you have $f(-\Delta c + a) = a'$

Moreover, $i(a-\Delta c) = ia - i\Delta c = ia = b$. So it's not quite $a$ that's the antecedent, but $a-\Delta c$

Comment: I looked right at $fdc = fa - a' \Rightarrow a' = f(a - dc)$ before I posted the question and completely missed that connection!